# Angular2 Router : 3.0.0-alpha.8 + Can't resolve all parameters for provideRouter: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Project in angular2 with router version "3.0.0-alpha.8". While loading apis it shows error :

```
Can't resolve all parameters for provideRouter: (?, ?) .

Error : BaseException$1@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:955:27
```

Below given are the files used:

app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './First/first.component';
import { HeroListComponent } from './First/first-list.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './Login/login.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [

{ path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent },
{ path: 'first', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }

];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
provideRouter(routes)
];
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { Hero } from './Hero/hero.component';
 import { HeroDetailComponent } from './First/first.component';
 import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, provideRouter } from    '@angular/router';
 import { LoginComponent } from './Login/login.component';
 import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
   directives: [ HeroDetailComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
   providers: [provideRouter]
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private router:Router) {
   }
   title = 'Tour of Heroes';
   selectedHero: Hero;
   onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
   }
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the systemjs config https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the router correctly.
Go to your main.ts file where you bootstrap angular and find the list of providers you have. it should look similar to this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [
        // Providers
    ]
```

You need to add your const `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to this list, like so:

```
import {APP_ROUTE_PROVIDERS} from 'app.routes';
bootstrap(AppComponent, 
    [
        APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]
```

and then remove `providers: [provideRouter]` from your `app.component.ts`